# multiple embed into one message

Tags: javascript, discord

i really need help.
How can i multiple embed into one message instead of sending 1 by 1?

```
 if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "find")) {
      const item = game.data.members;
      const GQ = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1);
     let ign;
     let gq;

      for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        if (item[i].task_finished_week < GQ) {
          ign = item[i].name;
          gq = item[i].task_finished_week;
          const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setTitle(ign)
          .addField('Weekly GQ', gq);

        msg.channel.send({ embed });

        }
      }
```

Comment: Please explain your question context (Technology, What you are trying to do, etc)

Comment: i am trying to get a match from a json file. lets say age "18. those who matches age "18", their name will be list out . my problem is, the bot is sending 100 msgs if found 100matching age. i am trying to embed 100maching into 1 embed msg.